# SOLR Query to fetch child pages

Tags: solr, aem

How can I fetch the immediate child elements of a parent node. We've implemented SOLR with CQ5 and I'm having page structure like /content/parent/child/subchild. So if I give path as /content/parent, then the SOLR query should return me only /content/parent/child i.e. immediate child and not the subchild. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following JCR SQL2 Query:

```
String sql= "SELECT * FROM nt:unstructured WHERE jcr:path LIKE '"+path+"/%' AND NOT jcr:path LIKE '"+path+"/%/%'";
```